# Validating and Marshalling big XML file?

Tags: java, xml, marshalling

I have got big XML  file of size 2GB to 4 GB which i am getting through third pasrty vendor. Now i need to do two type of operation
for different usescases :-

*Use-case 1 :-*

Validate some of the values in XML.

*Use-case 2 :-*

Marshal the XML to java object for some processing.

Now my question is whats the best way of doing it. Can i validate specific element without parsing for Usecase 1.

Second question is how can I marshal such big file without getting `OutOfMemory` exception or with best utilization of memory for use-case 2?

Comment: If it is one time activity, than you can do this using java by increasing heap memory.

Comment: Its not one time activity

Comment: Don't read it at once, use the STaX API to read the file (which reads a small portion of the file). You also might want to take a look at, for instance, Spring Batch to help you read/process that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the document is that large, you will want to use an event based parser such as SAX and marshall objects by hand.  This will allow you to process the document as a stream rather than reading in the whole document at once.

Here's a brief article discussing event based parsing versus tree-based parsing:

http://www.saxproject.org/event.html